# Play youtube video in offline mode?

Tags: ios, youtube, video-streaming

I want to play YouTube video when we redirect from internet area to non internet area.

Like I am having internet access at some point and I played Youtube video, and after some

times my internet connection is loosed, but now I want to play all those video which I played

previously.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to write any code for this but only tell you the route you probably need to take.  As with any online media, If you don't have access to the internet, well you can't really get the data.  What you need to do is capture the data which is coming in from any media and save it on the device.  When the user then clicks on a video which has been previously saved while not connected to the internet, you can play the saved video file.  There isn't really a simple quick way to do this, just do some research on saving streaming video or downloading video and saving to device.

Comment: I expected some example or link to buffer video and streaming...?

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions when you are stuck, you can easily use google to look that up instead of asking me to search google for you to provide you a link.

Comment: I just asked to whom who have knowledge about this .. and did this task previously... your answer is such a normal answer.. every one know this... i want some unique

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any caching mechanism for a browser that could do that 'off the box'. This wouldn't make much sense anyway because the cache would get full with only a few videos.

The only way that comes to mind is to download the video of interest while connected and play it with your favorite media player. There's bound to be a few addons depending on the browser you use, I use [VideoDownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) for Firefox but for iPhone [this blog](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/apple/3417482/how-download-youtube-videos-your-iphone-or-ipod-touch/) seems to have some instructions.