# HTTP Live streaming on iOS device with Youtube Videos

Tags: ios, http, http-live-streaming

I have tried my code by hosting .m3u8 and .ts file on my LocalHost its working fine. I want to show a Youtube video in iOS, Is Youtube using HTTP live-streaming so that this is possible? Any idea?

Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590022/play-youtube-video-in-offline-mode

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
- (void)embedYouTube {

videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
<html>\
<head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
iframe {position:absolute; top:50%%; margin-top:-130px;}\
body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
</style>\
</head>\
<body>\
<iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"240px\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen>    </iframe>\
</body>\
</html>", videoURL];

[webView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];

}
```

Where `videoURL` is the youtube link to the video.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm using MPMoviePlayerController for video streaming.

Comment: As far as I remember, there's no way to play youtube videos within a MPMoviePlayerController. Please let me know if I'm mistaken and you'll find a solution to this :)
P.S. You should have specified that you're using the MPMoviePlayerController class.